# How to Assert a list in unit test?

Tags: vb.net, list, unit-testing, assert

I have this test method where I am testing a list. It is working fine but I want to simplify the Assert.

```
<TestMethod()> Public Sub Method_Scenario_ReturnsList()
  'Arrange
    Dim sut As New ClassName()
  'Act
    Dim result = sut.ListMethod(parameter)
  'Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("1", result(0).ID)
    Assert.AreEqual("One", result(0).Name)
    Assert.AreEqual("2", result(1).ID)
    Assert.AreEqual("Two", result(1).Name)
End Sub
```

Is there a way to simplify this in just two lines of Assert where I check all the IDs and all the Names? Something like

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual({"1","2"}, result.Select(Of ))
```

Is there a syntax to do that? I am noob in VB.net

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual({"1","2"}, result.Select(Function(item) item.Id).ToArray())

CollectionAssert.AreEqual({"One","Two"}, result.Select(Function(item) item.Name).ToArray())
```